# TeamCity NuGet Package Restore Failing After Upgrade to 10.x

Tags: teamcity, nuget-server

Been getting the old NuGet Installer Failed error after upgrading to TeamCity 10.x.

The Build Server is on a local VM and the NuGet Server is on another VM on RackSpace. I can authenticate using the feed and the credentials, and the package is created and exists. I can update the package manually in VS using the same credentials. Just no joy in TeamCity build.

```
[restore] Unable to find version '1.1.0.16' of package 'Velociraptor'.
[23:00:39][restore] Process exited with code 1
[23:00:39][Step 1/4] Step NuGet Installer failed
```

This was working prior to the upgrade from 9.1.7 to 10.x

I've looked at the other answers but none have worked so far.

What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't moved up to 10.x yet, but wondered if maybe the default version of NuGet.exe changed? Does your NuGet server support a pinned version of the NuGet.exe client? Have you tried with earlier versions of the client?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd, it was set to use the default 3.3.0 and I've pinned it to 2.8.6 and that seems to be getting to Step 2 at least.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. I can't pull some NuGet packages (although others are fine?) and I can't even install new versions of NuGet.exe from Administration -> Integrations -> Tools.

Comment: Can't mark @EvolveSoftwareLtd comment as the answer but that is what worked for me in this instance. Now on to figuring out why the pull requests aren't functioning like before, but that is another topic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't moved up to 10.x yet, but expect that maybe the default version of NuGet.exe has changed.

If your NuGet server supports a pinned version of the NuGet.exe client then it might be worth trying with an earlier versions of the client. This can be changed in the Administration section.

Hope this helps.